# Document ready in new window, cross-domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

how can I check if the document in new window is ready AFTER the document reloads.

Here is my example:

I need to get a search result page to new window from some site (it's cross-domain). I need to first make POST request (they probably store search params in session) and then go to reslut page.

Here is my code:

```
var windowname = "window"+(new Date().getTime()); // so I can open multiple windows, not very relevant 
var new_window = window.open("", windowname); // prepare named window

// prepare form with post data targeted to new window
var dataform = $("<form method='post' target='"+windowname+"' action='https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembldb/compound/smiles/'><input name='smiles' value='"+$("#id_smiles").text()+"'></form>");

// Need to get the form into page for Mozilla, webkit allows to submit forms that are not in page
$("body").append(dataform);

// submit the form and remove it, no need to keep it
dataform.submit().remove();

// form opens in my new window
$(new_window.document).ready(function(){

    // this is carried out apparently too soon, because the POST data didn't work
    // when I use timeout (commented below, but i don't like this solution) it works
    window.open("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembldb/index.php/compound/results/1/chemblid/asc/tab/smiles", windowname);
    // setTimeout( function(){window.open("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembldb/index.php/compound/results/1/chemblid/asc/tab/smiles", windowname)}, 1000);
});
```

On that site the first make POST request with AJAX and then they simply, but since it's cross-domain, it is impossible for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not possible. Even some browser throw exceptions if you use reference of new_window (cross domain).
 I got following exception. while trying to access reference of new window with url `http://www.google.com` (Browser Chrome). and reference has no property with it.

**Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.google.co.in/ from frame with URL [Document ready in new window, cross-domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724804/document-ready-in-new-window-cross-domain). Domains, protocols and ports must match.**

Comment: Yes, I came across this issue as well, although I don't need to access the frame I just want to know went it is loaded, but these two things cant be separated most likely...

Comment: you should use setTimeout( with aprox timerout ) to delay change of url of that window.

Comment: If you look in my question again, you may see that I did this actually (its treacherously commented at the end :-) ), I just don't like this solution, because it depends on internet connection and if shall further parametrize the search query, the response delay may vary a lot (it's chemical compound search and there is a great difference between identity and substructure or similarity search performace)

Comment: Yes,  I saw that. but that code will never execute as ready will never get fired. I means you can set a value of timer so that it always execute your code after page load as more than 2min.

Comment: No, it works this way. At least in webkit (Chrome). Ready will fire, but too early.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the javascript code which is in cross domain, for that you should use either JSONP concept ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP )/ Cross Origin Resource Sharing( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing ).

Just few changes should be done in apache server settings.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think to use CORS, the responding server should have Access-Control-Allow-Origin etc. header in response, so I'd have to persuade them to put it there and I don't see a way to send POST data with JSONP. Could you present some simple example?